# Why using X is not center in {\raggedright\arraybackslash}X

Tags: tables, tabularx

When I used:

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}cccc}
```

It gives all the content moving to the left and leaves some space on the right hand side table (Example 1)

```
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
```

It will not give center. (Example 2)

[image]

my Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}cccc}
 \toprule
  & \thead{\small {\textbf{Mean}}\\ \textbf{(\%)}} & \small {\textbf{N}}
  & \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Deviation}}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}& \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Error}} \\ \textbf{Mean (\%)}} \\
 \midrule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (AA)} & 94.51  & 60 & 5.55 & 1.33 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (BB)} & 40.32  & 60 & 12.13 & 3.43 \\
 \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \caption{Example 1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
 \toprule
  & \thead{\small {\textbf{Mean}}\\ \textbf{(\%)}} & \small {\textbf{N}}
  & \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Deviation}}\\ \textbf{(\%)}}& \thead{\small {\textbf{Std. Error}} \\ \textbf{Mean (\%)}} \\
 \midrule
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (AA)} & 94.51  & 60 & 5.55 & 1.33 \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (BB)} & 40.32  & 60 & 12.13 & 3.43 \\
 \end{tabularx}
 \caption{Example 2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` in the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring wrongly the columns: you probably want

```
>{\raggedright}Xcccc
```

and to get rid of the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` in the first column.

I believe that using `siunitx` and `tabular*` is better.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp!]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=2.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
  & {\thead{Mean \\ (\%)}}
  & {\theadfont N}
  & {\thead{Std. Dev. \\ (\%)}}
  & {\thead{Std. Error \\ Mean (\%)}} \\
\midrule
\textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (AA) & 94.51  & 60 & 5.55 & 1.33 \\
\textit{Aaaaaa example dataset} (BB) & 40.32  & 60 & 12.13 & 3.43 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Example}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I left only the necessary packages. Note the less heavy input: since you set `\theadfont` it's useless to repeat `\small` and `\textbf`.

[image]

Comment: thanks. Brillant! Just one question. Is there a way to make some small space on the left and and on the right hand side? like 0.3mm space

Comment: @aan When tables are spread out to cover the whole available width, I'd not add padding at either side. You can use `@{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}` at the beginning and remove `@{}` at the end of the column specifications.